# converting or casting LPWST into BSTR

Tags: c++, windows, wchar

How to convert LPWSTR into BSTR ? LPWSTR is WCHAR * and BSTR is OLECHAR *, OLECHAR is again of type WCHAR, simply type casting will work ? or we need to do some extra effort ? It is showing bad conversion error/warning.

Answer (score 3):

You do it like this

```
BSTR pBstr = SysAllocString(szWCharString);

// do something with the BSTR here ...

SysFreeString(pBstr);
```

You have to remember to deallocate the space used for the conversion by calling `SysFreeString` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Roger, Actually I have a function which takes BSTR as parameter, when I am passing LPWSTR as an argument it is showing bad conversion error/warning.

Comment: @Anand Yes, it (the compiler) tells you that you have to pass the right object. You can't cast since it's a different thing. So you have to create a new object (a BSTR) and pass this to the function. Don't forget to release the object after use.

Answer (score 1):

The BSTR consists of a OLECHAR[] and a length information prepended to the string. The BSTR is  a pointer to the OLECHAR[] part. But the BSTR functions require the length information (capacity and curent length).

You need the [SysAllocString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891285.aspx) function to allocate the whole structure.

Comment: No, you can't. The `LPWSTR` variable is not allocated with `SysAllocString` but a simple variable of 4 bytes. But when you have a BSTR pointer, and have casted the value to a `LPWSTR`, you may can pass this pointer to `SysFreeString` while implicitly casting it to BSTR. But it's your responsibility that you did it in this way. Usually a cast is in expression that you it better than the compiler and you should be confident to take this spiry way.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem you can click the "Accept" check m ark.